# Why dom events doesn't work inside controller in angularjs

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I have a controller like this which is attached to `body` of html.

```
angular.module("app", [])

.controller("MyCtrl", function($scope) {

   // Here I perform some jquery code listening for click event

   $("a").click(function() {
      $(this).toggleClass("active");
   });

});
```

Now, I want to know why this doesn't work inside controller. I know, if I put it into directive then it does work.

Comment: What do you mean, it doesn't work? Be a bit more specific.

Comment: Not a direct answer, but in my opinion, DOM operations should never be inside controller. Is there some specific purpose for this approach? Like you said, it works in directive.

Comment: I think you should read again what an AngularJs controller is. That function you defined is used as a constructor

Comment: Please place whole code here..how are you trying to access this controller. If possible also make a plunker of it.

Comment: In that code do an `alert($("a").length)`

Comment: it is javascript -- it does not matter if it is inside controller, directive or global scope. So show us your console log.

Comment: Probably corresponding DOM is not yet rendered when you are binding click event.

Comment: @dfsq, you are right, I am using routing to render some parts of html which was not loaded before event binding. So that's the problem. Thanks for your comment.

Comment: @ashish2expert Take a look at my answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**[Don't mix up JQuery with AngularJS](https://stackoverflow.com/a/15012542/1575570)**, Since its not a Good Practice,

If you want some toggle feature use in-built **[ngClick](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngClick)** directive feature provided by `AngularJs` instead of using `JQuery` `$("a").click`

[**Sample Demo 1**](http://jsfiddle.net/gf5q0pmd/)

**[Sample Demo 2](http://jsfiddle.net/nw5ndzrt/)**

**[Sample Demo 3](http://jsfiddle.net/xttsa5vk/)**

**[Sample Demo 4](http://jsfiddle.net/f82p7ftr/)**

```js
function MainController($scope) {
  $scope.toggle = true;
}
```

```css
.box {
  color: white;
  text-align: center;
  height: 100px;
  font-size: 86px;
}
.on {
  background-color: green;
}
.off {
  background-color: red;
}
.box-show-setup,
.box-hide-setup {
  -webkit-transition: all linear 0.3s;
  -moz-transition: all linear 0.3s;
  -ms-transition: all linear 0.3s;
  -o-transition: all linear 0.3s;
  transition: all linear 0.3s;
}
.box-show-setup {
  opacity: 0;
  height: 0;
}
.box-show-setup.box-show-start {
  opacity: 1;
  height: 100px;
}
.box-hide-setup {
  opacity: 1;
  height: 0;
}
.box-hide-setup.box-hide-start {
  opacity: 0;
  height: 100px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>
<div ng-app ng-controller="MainController">
  <button ng-click="toggle = !toggle">Toggle!</button>

  <div class="box on" ng-show="toggle" ng-animate="'box'">On</div>
  <div class="box off" ng-hide="toggle" ng-animate="'box'">Off</div>
</div>
```

Also read this beautiful stuff

**[Using AngularJS? Stop using jQuery as a crutch.](http://joelhooks.com/blog/2013/07/27/using-angularjs-stop-using-jquery-as-a-crutch/)**